# How to force new snapshot in Valgrind massif using vgdb?

Tags: c, malloc, valgrind, massif

I am using `Valgrind` with the `massif` tool to monitor all parts of code that memory allocation occurs. In this case, I used this command to run my program using `Valgrind`:

```
valgrind --tool=massif --vgdb=full --pages-as-heap=yes --detailed-freq=1 --threshold=0.001 --max-snapshots=100 --time-unit=ms ./myprogram
```

My problem is that after 30 mins of running the program, it starts allocating more memory. I want to monitor that which parts of the code are allocating memory. I should notice that this is not a memory leak so I didn't use `Memcheck` rather I used `massif`. This command takes snapshots from memory at the beginning but after that, I have no snapshots from memory.

To solve this problem I used the `vgdb` command to take detailed snapshots in the way below:

```
vgdb detailed_snapshot
```

But looks like this command is using the captured snapshot, not a new one. So how can I take a new snapshot when I want?
Or should I release the captured snapshot in some way?

Comment: vgdb detailed_snapshot takes a new snapshot and saves it. It does not write a previously captured snapshot. If you obtain the same data as the previous snapshot, then likely it means that nothing new was allocated (or rather mmmap-ed as you are using --pages-as-heap=yes.